# how to press this button faster

Tags: modeling, animation

I've seen in a tutorial of someone showing he used the alt+O to smooth keys, and he just pressed and held the shortcut key and in a couple seconds he said it smoothed it the same amount as if he had pressed that shortcut around 80x. I can't hold it down and get the same result, I have to press it over and over and slowly see the keys smooth out, and it takes forever. How can I fix that.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After you used *Smooth Keys* once or any other command press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the last command. The command is repeated as long as you press and hold the keys.

Note that this spams the *Undo* history and limits your undo options.

Comment: so simple - and i couldn't find out ...‍♂️  +1

Comment: thank you. that helps a lot and luckily i have my history set to show last 128 steps :P